# htaccess RewriteCond !-f issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**UPDATE: Problem solved**
After many hours, I finally understood that the problem were in folder permission (757 instead of 755).

Damn, I feel like a idiot, but at least, problem solved :)

Thanks everyone!

---

I'm having a weird problem with my .htaccess and mod_rewrite.

Currently, I've the following .htaccess on my root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [NC,L]
```

**The problem is**:
I want to be able to access any existing file.

**i.e.:** mysite.com/anydir/myfile.png -> open the anydir/myfile.png
- mysite.com/anydir/script.php -> open anydir/script.php
- mysite.com/file.png -> open file.png
- mysite.com/notadir/imnotafile -> rewrite

But, everything works except the second point. I've a `file.php` in my `test` folder, but when I do `mysite.com/test/file.php`, it keep rewriting it, and it shouldn't...

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tested your .htaccess and don't see this rewrite. Maybe it's some caching problem.

Comment: I suspect that is some kind of server configuration. @OlafDietsche

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably do the trick:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE 1**

At this part of code:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

`[L]` Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules. So,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [NC,L]
```

Are not interpreted.

**UPDATE 2:**

The server will follow symbolic links:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

The server will disable multi views:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Rewrite engine will be enabled:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Base directory for rewrite will be `/`:

```
RewriteBase /
```

If request match a not existing file, continue:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

If request match a not existing directory, continue:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Rewrite to `index.php`, in a not sensitive case, and stop execution of next rules:

```
RewriteRule index.php [NC,L]
```

So, try the follow:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: It still have the same problem :(

Comment: Tried it, still rewriting .php files (but all other kind of files are not rewritten)

Comment: @HenriqueMouta, I think you are doing soma mistakes. From here I can access files directl if they existsy. So, `dir/file.php` or `a/b/c/d/e.php` will work if they are in correct location.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to get rid of the 404 error you could use

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

If you want to rewrite every directory i guess you should remove;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` = If request is not a existing directory, continue. And the problem is: `I want to be able to access any existing file.` (which may include directories)

Comment: Ah jeah sorry i got confused by an other similar post with .htaccess xD